# date range in mysql view cause slowness

Tags: mysql, date-range

I have a table in mysql table with this structure

id (primary index)
title,
date (datetime)
publicready (boolen)

and I create view like this

```
 CREATE view FROM SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE publicready AND date < NOW()
```

if I run a query against it takes 1.8 seconds but

if I remove the date range from the view the same query .0009 seconds

why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

i put an index on all columsn we are checking it did make slightly faster at 1.6

Comment: What's the use of selecting against `date > now()`, are these DB records from the future?

Comment: Could be the date is some future date (delivery, for instance).

Comment: should of actually been < but it could have just as easily been > the point is to make sure the date is not in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `now()` is that this disables MySQL from putting your query result in the cache.
If you remove the now, all selection criteria are constants and MySQL can just put the resultset of the view in the cache upon creation of the view.

With the `now()` that's impossible, forcing a full execution every time.

Comment: ok so how could I get all items that are not in the future without using now() or current_timestamp ?

Comment: Create an extra table: table_now - id:integer primary key, datenow:date. Do `replace into table_now (id, datenow) values (1,now())` and do `select t.* from tablename t inner join table_now n on (t.date < n.datenow) where publicready` Note that `table_now` will only ever have 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress, we fixed this by adding an extra status, whose value is 'future'. This allows to differentiate published and scheduled posts without even checking the date. If maintaining such a field is not an option for you, you could add an extra flag (e.g. is_future) and verify it's not true.

An alternative for you could be to keep a trace of the next item to get published in memcache. Then query against that date:

```
where publicready and date < :next_date
```

Doing so will allow the query to be cached by MySQL, since it'll eliminate the use of now().

Answer (score 1):

Put an index on the date column.

Comment: Rather than using now would it be possible to just use the current days' date at 11:59:59?  That way you could get some caching benefit (per @Johan's remarks).

Comment: I don't think so, items could be put in sometime during the current day that are not dated in the future